# Form Data In Meta Refresh - 500 Error

Tags: php, forms, get

I have a message form on multiple websites, they all send to the same php action so that I do not have to make multiple actions. After they send, it redirects them to a page with a success message.

This page is custom for each site so I tried making this so that the form would send a hidden link to redirect to after finished. Here is the code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='.$_GET[redirectlink]).'">
```

Every time this sends, I get a 500 error. I know that the form works correctly, because when I do

```
print_r($_GET[redirectlink])
```

It prints the correct link, and without that code, the message sends to my email correctly.

What is wrong in my code?

Thank in advance.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=<?php echo $_GET[redirectlink]?>">

Comment: If inside the php <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='.$_GET[redirectlink].'">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code, you are using a **)** along with `GET` variable.

**Modified meta:**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=<?php echo $_GET[redirectlink];?>">
```

Comment: I should have noticed, that was a simple mistake. I for some reason didnt notice that and thought that since it was in a php file that is didnt matter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy coding @carter-roeser